# Using Phaser's tilemap.putTile with multiple tilesets doesn't work

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser 2.6.2 and I have a tilemap with a background layer and an object layer, I want to add tiles to the object layer dynamically after the game starts.  I haven't found any answers to this issue so far but did come across others having different issues with putTile.

I have tried different ways to write the putTile command and load the layers but ultimately it either errors, puts a tile from my other tileset, or puts a blank (white) tile. The below code puts a blank (white) tile.

Here's the code:

```
//Add the JSON tilemap

this.map = this.game.add.tilemap('mk2064');

//Add the background tileset

this.backgroundtileset = this.map.addTilesetImage('backgroundTileset', 'gameTiles', 32, 32, 0, 0, 0);

//create the background layer

this.backgroundlayer = this.map.createLayer('backgroundLayer');

//add object tileset

this.objecttileset = this.map.addTilesetImage('objectTileset', 'objectTiles', 32, 32, 0, 0, 1);

//create the object layer

this.objectlayer = this.map.createBlankLayer('objectLayer', this.backgroundlayer.width, this.backgroundlayer.height, 32, 32);

//add a tile to the object layer

this.map.putTile(this.objecttileset[0], 5, 5, this.objectlayer);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually was loading the wrong tileset for objectTiles, so I'm closing this question.

I only realised once I changed the solution to use one tileset with all tiles in it and refactored the code...